# How to save data from python to mathematica?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

After running python code, the result is a dictionary `{"label1" = data1, "label2" = data2}`, and I am able to plot the two items at the same time. I can't change the way the data is saved since I am using other packages to create it.

What is the proper way to save this data on a file to be able to manipulate it in Mathematica?

Comment: `data1` etc is a list? number ? what?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the structure of your data1 and data2, but I think it is easy to work with Mathematica if you can save your data into csv files.

Try following codes if your data is pandas DataFrame.  You are expected to save data in separate csv files.

```
    sampleDict = {'label1':data1, 'lable2':data2}
    for item in sampleDict:
        sampleDict[item].to_csv(str(item) + '.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
data1 = [1, 2, 3]
data2 = [4, 5, 6]
dataset = dict(label1=data1, label2=data2)
headers = dataset.keys()
data = dataset.values()

def fromlist(lst):
    return ','.join(map(str,lst))

with open('C:/temp/temp.csv','w') as fout:
    fout.write(','.join(headers))
    fout.write('\n')
    fout.write('\n'.join(map(fromlist, zip(*data))))
```

Mathematica: using [SemanticImport](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html) :

```
SemanticImport["C:/temp/temp.csv", Delimiters -> ","]
```